# Using sympy.diffgeom.CoordSystem to connect two coordinate systems

Tags: python, sympy

I was trying to follow the documentation in sympy.diffgeom using my own example. Instead of using cartesian and polar coordinates, I tried using cartesian and toroidal coordinates.

Here is my code from an ipython session :

```
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem
from sympy.abc import theta, eta, psi
import sympy as sym

x,y,z,a = sym.symbols("x y z a")
m = Manifold("M",2)
patch = Patch("P",m)

cartesian = CoordSystem("cartesian",patch)
toroidal = CoordSystem("toroidal",patch)

from sympy import sin,cos,sinh,cosh
toroidal.connect_to(cartesian,[eta,theta,psi],
[(a*sinh(eta)*cos(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sinh(eta)*sin(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sin(theta))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))])
```

When I try to execute the last line here, the code simply runs endlessly.
Why is this not working ?

Comment: My purpose is to find the metric g and use it to determine the Riemann curvature tensor. I have implemented code which can find the metric.

I have tested the code and it returns the correct entries for the metric. Personally, I would prefer writing my own implementation for determining the Riemann curvature tensor, but since there is an implementation in sympy.diffgeom, I would love test it for the coordinate systems described above.

Comment: Are you working in 2 or 3 dimensions? Why did you declare your manifold as 2 dimensional but passed 3 parameters to the connect_to() method?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to alter the dimension for the manifold. It should be 3! Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put *inverse=False* as an argument in *.connect_to( ... )*:

```
toroidal.connect_to(cartesian,[eta,theta,psi],
[(a*sinh(eta)*cos(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sinh(eta)*sin(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sin(theta))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))], inverse=False)
```

It's likely that SymPy's solver encounters a lot of difficulty in inverting the transformation equations.

If you want to use the inverse transformations, I suggest call *.connect_to( ... )* a second time, manually specifying the inverse transformations:

```
cartesian.connect_to(toroidal, ... , ... , inverse=False)
```